# Edit Url for a FB Page Tab App - does not send signed_request (gets invoked as a GET and not a POST)

Tags: facebook-apps

When admin clicks the 'Go to App' on edit fan page, I am expecting the edit URL to invoke thru a POST along with a signed_request; instead the URL is getting called thru a GET with a ?fb_page_id=nnnnnn argument (where nnnnn is the pageId). No signed_request is received. I have filed [this bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/290212731027764?browse=search_4f14be923851c2d53793907) with Facebook (probably should be a key security enhancement, if this is not implemented yet)

Am I missing something, has anybody managed to get the signed_request on the invocation of **Edit Tab URL** ?

Btw, I have already managed to get the **Page Tab URL** to work and process the invocation that comes thru as a POST and a signed_request. All that is working fine, just looking for the **Edit Tab URL**.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a pretty common problem posted on SO lately.  If the docs say you're supposed to get a signed_request, then you should file a bug with Facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Looks like someone recently entered this as a bug.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/290212731027764

You should go there and me-too the bug so Facebook can send it higher up in their triage!

Comment: :-), That was me entering the bug (I also mention that in the question above). Thanks for taking a look at this and I hope Facebook can come back with the resolution. If this is true, then it a security issue and they are potentially making it difficult for Tab app developers to do avoidable security protection..